# What does yield(i) mean in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I'm learning the Coroutines of Kotlin.

The Code A is from the artical https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coroutines/flow.html

What does `yield(i)` mean in Kotlin?

**Code A**

```
fun foo(): Sequence<Int> = sequence { // sequence builder
    for (i in 1..3) {
        Thread.sleep(100) // pretend we are computing it
        yield(i) // yield next value
    }
}

fun main() {
    foo().forEach { value -> println(value) } 
}
```

Comment: If you know any Python, `yield(i)` is very similar to a Python generator function's `yield i`. But in Kotlin it's not a language feature, it's just a `suspend fun`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a coroutine feature. This code is an example for comparison to coroutine Flows. Sequences are iterators that evaluate each element lazily. A list contains all values ahead of time, but a sequence only calculates each value when it's requested in something like a `forEach` call (a "terminal" sequence function).

The above code is just simulating a sequence that takes a tenth of a second to compute each of its values. It's just producing the numbers 1, 2, and 3. `yield()` is how the `sequence` builder function is told to produce another value to be consumed.

The `sequence` builder function lets you pass a lambda that calculates values one at a time and returns them by calling `yield()`.

It's more common not to use the builder, but rather convert some collection into a Sequence with `toSequence()` and then you can chain operations like `map` on the Sequence and they won't be evaluated until a terminal operation like `forEach` is called. This has the benefit of avoiding intermediate Lists from being allocated for each operation.

Answer (score 0):

Calling `yield(something)` in [`sequence`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.sequences/sequence.html) means the [`iterator of the Sequence`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.sequences/-sequence/#functions) `hasNext()` and you will get `something` when you call `next()`.

After the user of the iterator calls `next()` and then `hasNext()` again, the execution will resume from the `yield`.

---

It looks pointless when it is just yielding 1 2 3. But consider doing a binary tree traversal. Pre-order, in-order, or post-order are all very easy to write in recursive code. We can use the call stack to remember what to do next.

When we want to build an iterator, we lose all that good stuff. We have to use an explicit stack to remember what nodes to visit next - unless we use the `sequence` function.

The [same fringe problem](https://wiki.c2.com/?SameFringeProblem) is an example for the power of that.

---

I disagree with the other answer stating that "this is not a coroutine feature".
Being able to resume at the middle of execution is the definition of **co**routines. Contrast that to **sub**routines which has to run from its start.

We very often use "coroutines" to refer to the concurrency constructs in Kotlin. The sequence building is not part of those, but still an example of coroutines.